# POST DATA SENT FROM AN ANDROID APP LOST DUE TO DOMAIN REDIRECT

Tags: php, android, redirect, post, cross-domain

My android app used to fetch JSON data through a POST request to the site https://example.org. Now the domain name has been changed to https://example.ac.in. I have hosted the old https://example.org to another server and gave it a redirect with a wildcard. My problem is, the post data being sent from the android app is lost and .ac.in domain is not getting the data but my app is getting a response from the new domain. I came to know that POST data lost during redirect. Please help me if there is any way around so that my app can send data to my new domain.
Please note, I can't change the app at this moment so making a GET request from the app will not possible as the app is being used by many users and the app is not in the app store.
Update : Making HTTP 308 redirect crashing the app.

Comment: You need to write some code on the example.org site to take the POST and put it into a new request to the real site. Then wait for the response and echo it back to the app. Either that or simply make it act as a proxy server which always forwards to the same place (basically the same process I just described, except maybe you can use ready-made software to do it.)  A redirect is always a GET, so that's why it fails to pass on the data currently.